# custom button padding and text size issue

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view by extending `LinearLayout` to make it as a button with icon and text.

Here is the class -

```
public class FancyButton extends LinearLayout {

    private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 3.0f;

    private String mButtonText;
    private String mFontName;
    private float mButtonTextSize;
    private int mBackgroundColor;
    private int mSeparatorColor;
    private Drawable mIcon;

    private Typeface mButtonTextTypeface;

    private Bitmap maskBitmap;
    private Paint paint, maskPaint;
    private float cornerRadius;


    public FancyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public FancyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FancyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        if (attrs != null) {

            parseSignInButtonAttrs(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, R.style.FancyButton);


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_button_widget, this, true);

            setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);


            ImageView buttonIconImageView = (ImageView) getChildAt(0);
            View separator = getChildAt(1);
            TextView buttonTextView = (TextView) getChildAt(2);

            if (null != mButtonTextTypeface)
                buttonTextView.setTypeface(mButtonTextTypeface);

            setBackgroundColor(mBackgroundColor);

            buttonIconImageView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
            separator.setBackgroundColor(mSeparatorColor);

            buttonTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            buttonTextView.setText(mButtonText);
            buttonTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mButtonTextSize);

            if (null != mFontName)
                mButtonTextTypeface = TypefaceLoader.get(getContext(), "fonts/" + mFontName);

            initCornerRadiusDraw(context);

        }
    }

    private void initCornerRadiusDraw(Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    private void parseSignInButtonAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr, final int defStyleRes) {
        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FancyButton, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        mFontName = a.getString(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonFont);
        mButtonText = a.getString(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonText);
        mBackgroundColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonBackgroundColor, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.app_blue));
        mIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonIcon);

        mButtonTextSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonTextSize, 12);

        mSeparatorColor = CommonUtils.getDarkerShade(mBackgroundColor);

        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);

        super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

        if (maskBitmap == null) {
            maskBitmap = createMask(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        }

        offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
    }

    private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height) {
        Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

        return mask;
    }
}
```

Now this creates a button like following -

[image: text size appears large and padding not taking effect]

So as you can see, the text appears large and also padding is not being added.

```
<com.sachingutte.testapp.views.FancyButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_box"
        custom:buttonBackgroundColor="@color/app_blue"
        custom:buttonIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        custom:buttonText="@string/dashboard"
        custom:buttonTextColor="@android:color/white"
        custom:buttonTextSize="12sp" />
```

**Edit**  Layout inflated -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@color/app_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</merge>
```

Comment: mButtonTextSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonTextSize, 12); change 12 to 10 and check

Comment: @Pravin The problem is `12sp` text size applied to this custom view and default button widget does not match. When same unit size is used in layout, it appears as it should. It is this view that makes text appear large. It's not in proportion and not scaling with device's density.

Answer (score 0):

### Padding

From the screen you've provided I can see that the padding is actually being applied. I can see that in a way the `1dp` wide `View` is displayed:

[image: padding]

You're just setting it to a relatively small value (`20px`).

---

### Text size

The problem is with this call:

```
mButtonTextSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonTextSize, 12);
```

As you can read from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getDimension(int,%20float)):

> Unit conversions are based on the current DisplayMetrics associated with the resources this TypedArray object came from.

So there is unit conversion involved when you call `getDimension`. Therefore you will not get the `sp` value, but a converted value based on a particular screen.

What you can do is:

1. If you want your default text size to be exactly `12sp`, you can get it with this:

```
float defaultTextSize = 12 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics.scaledDensity;
```

2. Get your value with this:

```
mButtonTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FancyButton_buttonTextSize, (int) defaultTextSize);
```

3. Set it to your `TextView` this way:

```
buttonTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mButtonTextSize);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check out text size fix as you suggested. But about padding, even I give it large value like say 100dp; the padding still remains same as shown in image.

Comment: @SachinGutte is your `rounded_box` drawable a `9-patch`?

Comment: Actually, background `rounded_box` does not take effect on custom view.  It's there because I forgot to remove it. I am applying rounded border directly on view with `onDraw()`.

Comment: @SachinGutte yep, about that... first of all instead of overriding `draw()` you should override `onDraw()`, AND what more important, in every single drawing pass you are creating two bitmaps which you never recycle nor reuse. This will for sure cause an `OutOfMemory` exception.

Comment: @SachinGutte and after a further look, try to pass `canvas` instead of `overscreenCanvas` into the `super.draw(...);` (just for a test). This might also cause a problem with your layout's paddings.

Comment: Okay. I'll fix those issues and check again. :)